# access each value of associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

hello how can i access or echo each element of this associative array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rule] => admin/user
            [title] => Users Management
            [target] => _parent
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [rule] => admin/user/add
                            [title] => Add New User
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rule] => admin/category
            [title] => Category Mangement
            [target] => _parent
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [rule] => admin/category/add
                            [title] => Add New Category
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to know which loop will support this and how

Comment: In what order?  Could you give an example of the output you're expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that using [**`array_walk_recursive()`**](http://fr.php.net/array_walk_recursive), with a callback function that would do an echo, would be quite a good solution.